# Problems creating let's encrypt cert on Mac OS: invalid header value

Tags: lets-encrypt

Three months ago I could create Let's Encrypt certs on Mac successfully by following the instructions in [this tutorial](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/tutorial-for-os-x-local-certificates-and-shared-hosting/6859?source_topic_id=8407).

Now that I have tried to do exactly the same, the let's encrypt updated itself and it shows me the following error:

```
Macbook$ pwd
/Applications/certbot
Macbook$ ./certbot-auto certonly --standalone -d domain1.com -d domain2.com -d domain3.com -d domain4.com
Requesting root privileges to run certbot...
  /Users/Me/.local/share/letsencrypt/bin/letsencrypt certonly --standalone -d domain1.com -d domain2.com -d domain3.com -d domain4.com
Password:
An unexpected error occurred:
ValueError: Invalid header value 'CertbotACMEClient/0.8.0 (darwin 10.10.5\n) Authenticator/standalone Installer/None'
Please see the logfiles in /var/log/letsencrypt for more details.
```

I removed the letsencrypt folder and tried this time installing `git clone https://github.com/certbot/certbot` but I still get the same error :(

I don't know if [this is the same reported issue](https://github.com/certbot/certbot/issues/3120) at github and I don't know either whether this has been solved or not.

I just tried again by downloading one more time the clone file but, it still doesn't work. :(

Does anybody know how to fix this??? Or is there another and simple way out there to get the certs (for example, online)?

I have found [this one](https://gethttpsforfree.com/) but it still looks complicated.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too, and this pull request (that has been merged to master) seems to have fixed it:
https://github.com/certbot/certbot/pull/3118

Note that after updating your git checkout to this code, you still may still see the issue if a cached version of certbot is used or if certbot-auto updates itself and overwrites the fix from the source code.

Note the recommendation in [this comment](https://github.com/certbot/certbot/pull/3118#issuecomment-224028128) to remove cached files and run with `--no-self-upgrade`:

```
$ rm -fr ~/.local/share/letsencrypt
$ ./certbot-auto --no-self-upgrade --debug certonly ...
```

Comment: I have tried removing `-rf` both the let's encrypt and the certbot folders, and then adding `--no-self-update --debug` and I am still getting the same error. I have tried to remove everything again and install it in a different folder and I get the same error again. Is there other way to get the certs?